# Rlp vs rlpx: the specified difference between rlp and rlpx?

Tags: rlp, rlpx

Rlp vs rlpx - the specified difference between rlp and rlpx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about RLPx, but for RLP(Recursive Length Prefix) is used as an encoding/decoding values in Ethereuma to ensure the values are compacted for quick transport across nodes, whereas [rlpx](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md#introduction) seems to be a secure and base version of RLP.

**Here are some useful links for RLP:**

- https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#rlp
- https://medium.com/coinmonks/data-structure-in-ethereum-episode-1-recursive-length-prefix-rlp-encoding-decoding-d1016832f919
- http://hidskes.com/blog/2014/04/02/ethereum-building-blocks-part-1-rlp/
- [How to RLP-encode messages in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42732/how-to-rlp-encode-messages-in-solidity/42797#42797)

From the link for RLPx: *"RLPx is a cryptographic peer-to-peer network and protocol suite which provides a general-purpose transport and interface for applications to communicate via a p2p network. RLPx is designed to meet the requirements of decentralized applications and is used by Ethereum."*

**Some useful links to RLPx:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029311/what-is-the-use-of-ethereums-rlpx-and-how-do-they-use-it-in-ethereum-ecosystem
- https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md

Hopefully, this clarifies a little bit.

Comment: thanks! I also see some mention of RLP as recursive linear prefix, not length prefix. Are they the same or used interchangeably?

Comment: sure, so far it looks like the official verbiage seems to be "length" in the [yellow paper] (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) - Appendix B